# Estimating column sums of $A_1,\ A_1 A_2,\ A_1A_2A_3,\ \ldots$

Tags: dynamic-programming, approximation, linear-algebra

Given $n\times n$ dense real valued matrices $A_1,\ldots, A_L$ let $P_i=A_1\ldots A_i$

For each $P_i$ I'm interested in obtaining the sum of all rows, and the sum of all columns.

Naive approach:

- takes $O(L n^2)$ time to get $L$ rows sums
- takes $O(L^2 n^2)$ time to get $L$ column sums

**Is there a way to estimate $L$ column sums faster than $O(L^2 n^2)$?**

We know that $n>L$.

---

More precisely, row sum $r_i$ and column sum $c_i$ are defined as follows
$$\begin{align}
r_i&=(1,\ldots,1) P_i\\
c_i&=P_i \left(\begin{matrix}1\\ \cdots\\1\end{matrix}\right)
\end{align}
$$

[image]

Comment: Why should the computation of the row sums take $O(Ln^2)$ but for the column sums $O(L^2n^2)$? They should take the same time? The $O(Ln^2)$ algorithm should also work for the column sums just by indexing differently?

Comment: See the hand-drawn diagram with naive approach, row sums reuse work so computing L of them has same cost as computing the last one

Comment: Ahh now I get it.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov do you have a lower bound on $L$? For example can we assume that $L \ge n^{2/5}$?

Comment: In my application $L$ is generally much smaller than $n$. Question basically comes down to asking if there's some smart way to summarize intermediate work so as to not require $O(L^2)$ passes